# WebView: Textbox inside IFRAME stops accepting input

Tags: ios7, uiwebview

test.html:

```
<body>
  <iframe src="input.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

input.html:

```
<input type="text" />
```

Tap inside the textbox and try typing. Everything works. Now tap outside the textbox and then tap inside again, or hide and show the virtual keyboard. Now typing does not work anymore.

Has anyone else seen this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

There's a hard to find, but known, bug in webkit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=133044

Answer (score 2):

We've been working with this issue for months, the only solution I've found is to use WKWebview instead of UIWebview. However, WKwebview has issues with iframes accepting cookies at the time of this writing.

https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView